# Track clicks inside iframe with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm trying to figure out a way of tracking clicks inside an iframe with jquery.
The iframe is locate on the same domain but still I don't seem to be able to make this work, here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var clicks = 0;
    $('#myframe').load(function() {
        alert('loaded');
        var that = $(this);
        that.contents().find('a').bind('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            clicks++;
            $('#clicks').html(clicks);
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
Clicks: <span id="clicks" >0</span>
<iframe id="myframe" src="test_iframe.php" width="500" height="500"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea of what could be wrong ?

I've saw other questions very similar to this one at SO but none of the answers solved my problem.

**UPDATE:**

I've updated my code at http://www.politicos.biz/stack/iframe_click.php with @Wes code, it works on jsfiddle but not on my site.

Comment: 1. Please don't use link shortening sites, 2. Don't update your question or add comments like: **STILL LOOKING FOR AN ANSWER :(**, we already know this because there are no answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the iframe is fully loaded befor you add the event.

I would expect the handler to be added with `.document`

```
$('body', window.parent.frames[0].document).click( 
    function(){} 
);
```

OR

```
$('body', $('templateframe')[0].document).click( 
    function(){} 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/wesbos/VxA8t/1/

```
$(function() {
    var clicks = 0;
    $('#myframe').contents().find('a').bind('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        clicks++;
        $('#clicks').html(clicks);
    });
});
```

You need to find the link first and then bind to it.

Your code should be something like this:

```
$('body', $('templateframe')).contents().find('a').click(function(event) {
  alert("Link Clicked");
});
```

Comment: your example at jsfiddle seems to work fine but my code at http://x.co/ZFR4 doesn't, could you please take a look ? thanks!

Comment: you changed the frame ID to Name. Just add id="myFrame" and it will work.

Comment: I've changed `name` to `id`  but still no luck, can you please double check ? thanks.

Comment: Ah, its because we have to wait for the iframe to fire document ready.

Im heading to bed, but it should look something like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/wesbos/VxA8t/2/

Comment: I truly appreciate your help but it still doesn't work, I've even changed the iframe to a very simple one (just in case), do you have a clue why this isn't working ?

Answer (score 0):

on the parent frame, create a function to be called from inside the iframe.

parent:

```
var click = 0;
function addClick()
{
    click++;
}
```

then, call it from the iframe

```
parent.addClick();
```

finally, simple refer to `click` for the number of click count. Hope this helps.